# CASE statement in DateDiff (Amazon Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to implement a CASE statement in a datediff function but it throws an `ERROR: syntax error at or near "case"`

Even when using a simplified query like the following, the error arises:

`select datediff(CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 'month' ELSE 'month' end,'2009-01-01','2009-12-31') as nummonths;`

Is it not possible to include CASE statement in the function?

Comment: Case is not needed in above query. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @RedshiftGuy you're correct, the `case` here was just to keep the initial structure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `datediff()` in [Redshift is a keyword](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html).  So, you cannot do what you want that simply.

Instead:

```
select (case when 1=1
             then datediff(month, '2009-01-01', '2009-12-31')
             else datediff(month, '2009-01-01', '2009-12-31')
        end) as nummonths;
```

I assume this is oversimplified code, because obviously the `case` is not needed in any version of this query.

Comment: Yes, it is simplified, here the `case` used is just to keep similar structure. Thanks a lot for your help Gordon!